# Datatable inline lookup editing

Tags: lookup, datatable, lightning-datatable, inline

[As showed here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDatatableInlineEdit) we can easily implement an inline editing of a data table.

Now I will need to have this editable field to behave like a lookup field and not a normal text field.

Is this possible? What is the best possible approach? Does Salesforce already have this feature planned in their roadmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No.

> What is the best possible approach?

For today, it would be to write your own [SLDS-based table](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/), or perhaps start from a [demo](https://gist.github.com/sfcure/d46652c1ba17070fcbfa4343e0f9943f)(note: this is only an example) that's already built. We don't even have a lightning:lookup field or the like, so you'll need to find one of those, too (they're really common, it's one of the most sought-after features that we don't have yet).

> Does Salesforce already have this feature planned in their roadmap?

Even if they did have it planned, I suspect you'd be able to implement it faster than waiting for it. At the time of this answer, we don't even know what features they have planned for Spring '19, much less further down the road, and I doubt they'll have it in the next release.

Comment: It looks like it's on the roadmap now. If you use an LWC datatable with a field type `reference` you will notice that an element called `lightning-formatted-lookup` is created in Summer '21 preview sandboxes, which seems to indicate it's being worked on. It doesn't properly work though...

Comment: @Steven.B Good to know. Looks like my answer was probably spot on, waiting for a couple of years to finally get proper support.

Comment: Right, and there's no mention of anything in the release notes so I still wouldn't hold my breath. But it looks promising